# cshtml local image not displaying in email html

Tags: c#, html, razor

I have an email written in .cshtml with an image tag:

```
<img src="../../../Images/logo.jpg">
```

the `logo.jpg` image exists in `MySite\Images\logo.jpg` and the email cshtml exists in `MySite\Views\Mail\ContactEmail.html.cshtml`

However, when I intercept the email with Papercut, there is the `x` icon indicating that the image is missing.  What could be causing the image not to load?  It works fine when using a URL in place of the image path.

When looking at the body of the email received in Papercut, it shows the image src as:

```
<img src="../../../Images/logo.jpg">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You specified a relative path.

Software that loads your HTML tries to request image from path:
`http(s)://BASE_URL/../../../Images/logo.jpg`

If you'd open it in browser hosted on `http://somesite.com/folder/folder/folder/ContactEmail.html` it would resolve your image url as: `http://somesite.com/Images/logo.jpg`.

If it was opened from local file `file://C:/folder/folder/folder/ContactEmail.html` it would resolve your URL to `file://C:/Images/logo.jpg`.

#### You need to:

1) Specify absolute URL (image *should* be hosted somewhere!)
or
2) You can encode your image in base64 and [use it like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8499716/12030195).

Answer (score 0):

When you view an HTML page in your browser, the browser can resolve relative paths by issuing a new HTTP request. When viewing an email, there is no URL to the HTML you're viewing, so the relative path should be resolved relative to ... what?

You *need* to use absolute URLs in an email, inline the image or send it as an attachment.